# Bootstrap 5 - justify-content - hower background for whole <li>

Tags: css

I have a code currently. This is dirt.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta class="nav-lin" tags -->
    <meta class="nav-lin" charset="utf-8">
    <meta class="nav-lin" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
      }
      .bg-dark {
        background-color: #90080a !important;
      }
      ul li {
        border-right: 1px solid #c88383;

      }
      ul li:hover {
        background-color: #7b0204;
      }
      ul li:last-child {
        border: none
      }
      .nav-link {
        padding: 0.5rem 0;
      }

    </style>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="text-white bg-dark">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-around">
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3"  href="#">Trio Ring Sets</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3" href="#">Bridal Ring Sets</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3" href="#">Wedding Band Sets</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3" href="#">Engagement Rings</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3" href="#">Ladies Wedding Bands</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3" href="#">Mens Wedding Bands</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link text-white py-3 " href="#">More</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="./bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to determine. Why the background does not extend to the whole li. How to achieve this? Elements are incorrectly arranged. I want to achieve → https://i.stack.imgur.com/2syo8.png. I would like to work on the Flex container.

I need to find out what is missing. This is my first time with bootstrap and a total of coding.

Comment: i can't understand what you want. can you explain more specific?

Comment: What I was looking for was "flex-grow: 1;" for <li>. I also had the text to center